# how to resolve joomla slow loading of home page with 8000 user groups?

Tags: performance, joomla

loading of home page becomes very slow after user with 8000 user group permission logs in.
not sure if it's due to the number of user groups or the number of contents connected to that thousands of user groups.

Comment: check with browser plugins which part is taking time? are they users or something else? Pagespeed, firebug etc.

Comment: thanks for the comment. the loading time is fine when user with 158 user groups logs in. but when user with thousands user groups logs in, the loading is very slow.

Comment: Can you check which part is taking time for user with 1000 grps? Hit webpage with pagespeed on or else paste link of your web app here with both user details (if they are not confidential), I'll check once.

Comment: hi. when i commented out the part where it pass the values in the getItems inside menu.php, the page loading is not a problem. so i think it's the retrieval of menu items for user with 1000 grps. appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Which version of Joomla? and why would anyone need thousands of user groups? (*that just doesn't make sense*)

Comment: joomla 2.5. we used it for document archival. anyway, thanks for all the comments. really appreciate your replies. we changed the menu plugins and it helped a lot to lessen the loading time. we were using ari yui before so i guess this plugin cannot cater too many user groups.